# Failed to print in C inside a thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, printf

I have created a simple sleepsort algorithm:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define ARR_SIZE 10

void *sleepSort(void *arg) {
    usleep(1000 * *(int*) arg);
    printf("%d ", *(int*) arg);
    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int arr[ARR_SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++)
        arr[i] = rand() % 100;

    pthread_t thr[ARR_SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++)
        pthread_create(thr + i, NULL, sleepSort, (void *)(arr + i));

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

However as I run it from Linux console nothing is printed until I enter a new character. However having modifierd my programme to add a newline on each printf it works as intended and I cannot understand why.

Comment: By default, stdout is line buffered when connected to a terminal. You'll need to send a LF, flush stdout, or disable buffering for stdout.

Comment: The many answers below citing stdout buffering are correct, but it should be emphasised that such buffering is not universal or standard. You can get unbuffered behaviour with different C libraries (maybe even with alternatives to glibc on Linux), with different platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However as I run it from Linux console nothing is printed until I enter a new character. However having modifierd my programme to add a newline on each printf it works as intended and I cannot understand why.

`printf()` uses buffered output to save system calls, and to do it efficiently, stdio package has several ways of doing this depending on the output device, by default.

- on `stdout` all the stdio routines use a buffer that only flushes its contents out, when the standard output is connected to a non tty device (this is, a file, a pipe, a socket, etc.)
- When `stdout` is connected to a physical tty (the console, or any tty device in `/dev`) then it switches to a mode in which it flushes the buffer only when the buffer fills up completely or a `'\n'` character is detected on ouput.  This is the behavior you observe.  When you put the new line character, the output gets shown, instead of being accumulated in the buffer.  Also, when you call one of the input routines to read (this is not general but some implementations do it, to allow you to print prompts not ending in a newline) a buffer flush is done first.  This also happens only when the output and the input are associated to a terminal.
- When you specify no buffer to `setbuff()`  then the output is unbuffered at all, so every printf will result in something written to standard output.

```
    setbuff(stdout, NULL);
```

If you don't want to change the default (and I recommend you not to set stdout buffer to `NULL` as performance will be affeced severely) you can, instead of using a newline character to force buffer flushing, just to intersperse a call to

```
    fflush(stdout);
```

in the places you want it to be written.

Finally, to answer your question, **the main reason to do so is performance**.  Buffered output strongly speeds up I/O and should be always used, except when some special characteristic (like debugging a program) is required.

Answer (score 2):

THe stdout is buffered and you need to force buffer flush by:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

or by printing LF

```
printf("\n")
```

If you want to see the output as it comes you can also disable buffering:

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

Documentation: [setvbuf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf)

Your program on godbolt (`'\n'` will not work as it is not terminal): https://godbolt.org/z/x4xT1M51e

Answer (score 2):

By default, `stdout` is line-buffered when connected to a terminal. A write to the system is only made when when a Line Feed is received, when the buffer fills up, when you manually flush the handle, or if you disabled buffering. Until then, output simply accumulates in a buffer.

So you'll need to

- send a Line Feed,

  ```c
  printf( "%d\n", ... );
  ```
- flush `stdout` manually,

  ```c
  printf( "%d ", ... );
  fflush( stdout );
  ```
- or disable buffering for `stdout`.

  ```c
  setbuf( stdout, NULL );
    //or//
  setvbuf( stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );
  ```

---

By default, `stdout` is fully-buffered when connected to something other than a terminal. This is also the default for other handles, whether they connected to a terminal or not. This is the same as line-buffered, except that Line Feeds don't cause a flush.